# Transition not smooth on width

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

So I have an envelope image and a letter image and I want the letter to smoothly transition out of the envelope `onmouseover` and I want the letter to smoothly transition back to place `onmouseout`. Now the first mouseover is perfect, the envelope slides to a `-400px` width in order to reveal the letter at a 1 second transition, but `onmouseout`, the envelope harshly snaps back to place and I have no idea why. Also, any additional mouseovers after the mouseout, it harshly snaps both the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events. Here is the code:

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang='en-us'>
    <head>
    <title>Test animation</title>
    <style>
     .displayNow {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      position: relative;
     }
     .letter {
      position: absolute;
     }
     .envelope {
      position: absolute;
      transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
      transition-timing-function: linear;
      -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
     }
    </style>
    <script>
    function moveOut() {
     var cssString = "margin-left:-400px;";
     document.getElementById('envelope').style.cssText=cssString;
    }
    function moveIn() {
     var cssString = "margin-left:auto;";
     document.getElementById('envelope').style.cssText=cssString;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class='displayNow'>
    <!-- Letter -->
    <img src='Letter.png' class='letter' id='letter' onmouseover='moveOut()' onmouseout='moveIn()' alt='letter'>
    <!-- Envelope -->
    <img src='Envelope.png' class='envelope' id='envelope' onmouseover='moveOut()' onmouseout='moveIn()' alt='envelope'>
    
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have also tried a `:hover` selector as opposed to the onmouseout/in JavaScript event which produced the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting margin-left to auto, set it to 0 (or wherever else it's supposed to originally sit at)

I believe CSS3 transitions do not know how to handle the auto settings.  This will apply to any transitionable element that can be set to auto.  I have ran into this problem several times when trying to transition heights and widths.

As far as the issue of snapping both ways after the initial transition, I'm not sure if that is related to the `margin-left:auto` issue or not but I would be willing to bet that it will fix it

Comment: That fixed it!!! Man, I'm gonna have to go look up some articles on that whole `margin:auto` thing and why it doesn't work with transitions! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: what if I'm using auto margins to center my image? how can I center my image and still have smooth width transition?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is coming to this question with similar issues (not seeing transitions work with auto dimensions) here is a great article from css-tricks on why it happens and what you can do to prevent it
[Using CSS Transitions on Auto Dimensions](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/)